# what type of image bug on jquery?

Tags: jquery, performance

can any one help please?

When I load image i try to get the two parameters:naturalHeight and naturalWidth;
That seems simple because they values are showing in the watch.

All works fine if i insert "debugger;" before and after the portion of code, all is fine, I see the values but when i remove the "debugger;" lines:
iImg.imgwidthand and iImg.imgheight  are equal to 0.

I detecte that when in debug mode  have the time to click fro next step, But in execute mode without debugging the time is CPU time.

thanks for a response if anybody have experienced this.

```
 var iImg = {
            "imgpath": "",
            "imgwidth": "",
            "imgheight": ""
        };

           var extImgLow = ".jpg";
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:2213/ImgstxtTab/imgs',
                async: false,
                cache:false,
                 success: function (data) {
                    var T = $(data).find('a:contains(' + extImgLow + ')');
                    for (var i = 0; i < T.length-1; i++) {
                        console.log("i: "+ i+1 +" =>" +  T[i].href + "   file: " +T[i].innerText);
                        var img = new Image();
                        img.src = T[i].href;
                        debugger;

                        if (img.naturalWidth > 0) {
                            iImg.imgwidth = img.naturalWidth;
                            iImg.imgheight = img.naturalHeight;
                            console.log(iImg.imgwidth +" - "+ img.naturalWidth);
                        }
                        debugger;
                    }
                 }
              });
```

working with jQuery v2.1.1;

Comment: You probably have to wait for the image to load first, using an `onload` handler.

Comment: An ajax success function doesn't wait for assets to load--just for a response.

Comment: Note that you'll also have issues with your `for` loop and the value of `i` when addind an async `onload` handler. I suggest using jQuery's `each` to create a closed scope.

Comment: I have allready teted wth each(function(index, value)... Yes  get these natural parametes but my problem is to sequential loading image for that i write this : var img = $("<img />").attr('src', imgPath).load(function () {
                        if (!this.complete || typeof this.naturalWidth == "undefined" || this.naturalWidth == 0) {
                            alert("Tableaux getImagesfrom directory" + "index.html" + "Image incorrect!");}
                        if (this.complete) { //done so get the naturalHeight..}